# Historical data usage on Android Pie

Tags: 9.0-pie, data-monitoring, oxygenos, oneplus-6

I'm trying to check my historical data usage on my OnePlus 6 (OxygenOS 9.0.6).

I used to be able to go to the Data Usage settings and use a drop-down list at the top to select different time periods, but trying this just now it only shows me the usage since the start of my current billing cycle, with no option to show any other period.

This is not the behaviour I was expecting, so I wonder if this specific to Android Pie on my OnePlus 7, or has Android Pie (or earlier) removed the ability to display data usage history.

Noticing that my billing cycle start date was wrong, I corrected it and found that the usage data shown now goes back to the start of the new billing cycle start date, so obviously it stores more data than is displays.

If more history is still recorded somewhere, how can I get access to it, and how far back would the history go? I'm comfortable with using `adb` if necessary.

<sup>My device is not rooted, nor can it be, but I'm comfortable with using ADB if necessary.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I use this apps to monitor my data usage I found it useful. You should try if you want.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter.lite&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dinternet+monitor+android&pcampaignid=APPU_1_6egZXfunKIv6wAP8_ovoCA

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glasswire.android&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dglasswire&pcampaignid=APPU_1_segZXchYxdb5BvHunLAF

Comment: I've used Internet Speed Meter Lite before, but it only shows you data it has recorded itself, so installing it now won't give me access to historical the data I'm after.  The same appears to be the case for Glasswire, so neither can help me access the usage data the OS has already recorded. Also, both apps need "Run at startup" permissions, so to be running in the background the whole time to record this data.